# Render on another machine in local network via Adobe Media Encoder

Tags: premiere, adobe-media-encoder

I am interested if I can set up Adobe Media Encoder so I could send render job from my macbook pro to a more powerful PC? Or at least, are there any solutions that would allow me to render videos faster and without slowing down my mbp?